# radio buttons requeridos - con angular material

Tags: angular

Estimados su apoyo es la primera vez que uso los componentes de angular material necesito poner requeridos estos radios buttons no lo puedo lograr su apoyó por favor. Gracias.

```js
<form (ngSubmit)="retiroFondo(monto)" #monto="ngForm">
<mat-radio-group #radioGroup="matRadioGroup" ngModel required>
<mat-radio-button value="SI"> SI </mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button value="NO"> NO </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<button
            [disabled]="!monto.valid"
            class="next"
            mat-button
            matStepperNext
          >
            Continuar
          </button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedes usar modelo de plantillas y estas usando mat-step

->Para manejar formularios revisa: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

->Si solo es un input no es necesario que tengas un formulario.

en tu .ts

```
opcion:String;
```

en tu .html

```
<mat-step [completed]="opcion!=null">
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="opcion" required>
 <mat-radio-button value="SI"> SI </mat-radio-button>
 <mat-radio-button value="NO"> NO </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<button class="next" mat-button matStepperNext>Continuar</button>
<mat-step>
```

Comment: Hola ok entiendo, por ahora  necesito que el botón continuar no se habilite si no marcan cualquier radio, con el código queme pusiste, sigue el botón habilitado, mesecito que este en disabled hasta que marquen una opción , gracias por el apoyo

Comment: lo esta haciendo pero a la inversa cuándo marca los radios el añade le disabled, debería ser al contrario remover el disabled al marcar un radio